# i am trying to pass string variable(City)from service to controller but it is not pass correctly

Tags: angular

```
  getCity(){
     let headers = new Headers();

     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
     return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'Misc/'+'City', { headers: headers})
       .pipe(map(data => data.json()),
       catchError((error: any) => {
         throw error;
       }));
   }
```

Comment: what your controller looks like?

Comment: if `City` is a variable which holds you `city code` or `city name` or `city id` you are passing it wrong, remove that "single quotes" i.e. `'City'` should be `City` or `$scope.City`

Comment: in my database grp_City column in that i m giving City key to multiple Cities

Comment: City is a hard code

Comment: actually i want to use this parameter in where condition. like.. select description from mstcommon where group_name = 'City' ...... so from service i want to pass parameter City to contoller in which get method will get called and 'City' parameter values will be passed to it